# How to add/remove child items in a RecyclerView, suggestions for an Order Restaurant App?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually i'm trying to make an app that will permise to take orders in a restoraunt.

As probably you know when a waiter take's an order he can add any item from a menu to record's (something like a notebook) and even additionally he can add a variant to added item.

Example, i have a pizza menu in my app when i press some items from my menu it's added to the notebook (Menu and Notebook are 2 RecyclerView) after i've added the type of pizza's i can "modify" them by adding a subitem or better a child to the main item.

Or better i have 3 different pizza's on my notebook by clicking on one of them i'll be able to add a variant chosen from another recyclerView as "PIZZA" and variant "WITH PEPERONI" or "WITHOUT PEPERONI" or "WITH MORE MOZZARELLA".

For now i think i'm doing fine with the app like i have yet all what i need, as you can see on this GIF i'm adding from recyclerView "FOOD" to the "NOTEBOOK" recyclerView some items and by pressing VARIANTI i'm able to add Child items to last added FOOD.

[image]
[image]

But the issue comes when i have to delete a single VARIANT added to a food i would have some suggestion on how can i like click on a single VARIANT and would be able to delete the single one.

Here is my Adapter code:

```
   public class AdapterPTERM extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPTERM.ExampleViewHolder> {

    private List<ItemPTERM> mExampleList;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private List<Variant> variants;
    private ManageAddRemoveCallbacks mManageAddRemoveCallbacks ;


    private View.OnClickListener varientClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getTag()!= null){
                int position = (int) v.getTag();
            }
        }
    };

    public interface  OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_pterm,parent,false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(v,mListener);
    }

    AdapterPTERM(Context context, List<ItemPTERM> exampleList){
        mExampleList = exampleList;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExampleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ItemPTERM item = mExampleList.get(position);

        holder.desc.setText(item.getBtnName());
        holder.qta.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQuant()));

        holder.variantsContainer.removeAllViews();


        // ADDING CHILD HERE

        variants = item.getVariants();
        if (variants != null && variants.size() > 0){
            for(Variant v : variants){
                View vView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.variant_layout,holder.variantsContainer,false);
                TextView nameTV = vView.findViewById(R.id.variant_name);
                nameTV.setText(v.getName());
                vView.setTag(position);
                vView.setOnClickListener(varientClickListener);
                holder.variantsContainer.addView(vView);

            }
        }

        tvAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                void onAddItem(true);
            }
        });

        tvRemoveItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                void onBtnClickRemoveItem(true);
            }
        });

        // NOT IMPORTANT (CHANGING FIELDS COLOR)
        if(position % 2 == 0 ){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C0C0C0"));

        }else if(position % 2 == 1){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView desc;
        public TextView qta;
        private LinearLayout variantsContainer;

        ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);


            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Desc);
            qta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Qta);
            variantsContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_child_items);

            try {
                mManageAddRemoveCallbacks = ((ManageAddRemoveCallbacks) this);
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException("ManageAddRemoveCallbacks must implement ManageAddRemoveCallbacksCallback.");
            }

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }



    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mExampleList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public interface ManageAddRemoveCallbacks {
        void onAddItem(boolean isAdded);

        void onBtnClickRemoveItem(boolean isRemoved);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can do so by either using swipe methodology or by inserting imageButtons and on their clicks perform the required tasks.

Comment: Actually i have yet the swipe methodology but it works with whole item and not with single variant

Comment: Ah yes it will work with whole item. So your best bet is to use clickListeners and on their clicks do the required tasks. Click listener can be a long or simple.

Comment: Actually as you can see i have yet "varientClickListener " in my adapter that when i click a variant works as clickListener but i don't know how can i manage it and use the clickListener on my Activity

Comment: You can use interfaces for that :) clean and simple.

Comment: Can you make an example of it?

Comment: yeah sure let me post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement interfaces on their respective `click listeners();`First go to your adapter and declare an interface like this:

```
 private ManageAddRemoveCallbacks mManageAddRemoveCallbacks ;

public interface ManageAddRemoveCallbacks {
    void onAddItem(boolean isAdded);

    void onBtnClickRemoveItem(boolean isRemoved);
}
```

Now in your viewHolder initialize your interface:

```
 try {
        this.mManageAddRemoveCallbacks = ((ManageAddRemoveCallbacks) currentFragment);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("ManageAddRemoveCallbacks must implement ManageAddRemoveCallbacksCallback.");
    }
```

Now in your **`bind`** method where you will add **click listeners** to your **views** assign values to your `interfaces`

```
  tvAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            void onAddItem(ture or false depending on your requirements);
        }
    });


tvRemoveItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                void onBtnClickRemoveItem(ture or false depending on your requirements);
            }
        });
```

Now after doing that you need to implement these interfaces in your activity/fragment something like this:

```
Your Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements YourAdapter.InterfaceName
```

so that you can use these. In this way you will get the values in your activity.

Comment: wait I posted it accidentally :D

Comment: as i doesn't have a fragment in currentFragment i should use "this right"?

Comment: And even tvAddItem and tvremoveItem says Cannot resolve symbol while onAddItem and onBtnClickRemoveItem are unused

Comment: Updated Adapter code by adding you elements can you check it on the question?

Comment: @JohnKarry yes I posted this code to give you the idea how it is done. You can change it according to your requirements :)

Comment: Actually what is tvAddItem and tvRemove item? should i create some local variables for it?

Comment: @JohnKarry And in your case you should change textview to your view like use holder.desc instead of what i wrote in the answer,
And by the way you can only do this using one interface too :)

Comment: they are textviews in your case you will use holder.desc and holder.qta or whatever you want to implement. :)

Comment: Actually holder.desc and holder.qta are the textview's from the Parent View, as you can see on the gif and the screen "1/4 LIMONCINO" "1" is DESC and QTA it's not element from the child

Comment: @JohnKarry please try to understand I am giving you the idea of how it is implemented. You don't need to copy paste my code. You can change is according to your own requirements. Interfaces can be implemented anywhere so don't worry about them.

Comment: Hm ok i got it but after optimizing it to my code the app crash when i add new item from the menu with error:  ManageAddRemoveCallbacks must implement ManageAddRemoveCallbacksCallback.
        at com.example.igardini.visualposmobile.AdapterPTERM$ExampleViewHolder.<init>(AdapterPTERM.java:133)
        at com.example.igardini.visualposmobile.AdapterPTERM.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterPTERM.java:45)
        at com.example.igardini.visualposmobile.AdapterPTERM.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterPTERM.java:16)

Comment: @JohnKarry that means you are getting this error `throw new ClassCastException("ManageAddRemoveCallbacks must implement ManageAddRemoveCallbacksCallback.");`

Comment: yeah but the problem is that i've implemented it

Comment: @JohnKarry initialize your interface in your adapter's constructor .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174330/discussion-between-johnkarry-and-umair).